# check field1 and field2 from single table

Tags: sql

In SQL:
          I want to check. From single table,

```
 if(field1 = 1 and DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= field2) then
        return count(*)
     else
        return "false"
```

thanks
v.srinath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (field1 = 1 AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= field2) 
                THEN   COUNT(*)     
       ELSE 0 
       END  
FROM SomeTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE  
    WHEN field1 = 1
    AND  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= field2
    THEN COUNT(*)
    ELSE 'false'
END
```

Note that this only works in the `SELECT` list, or `HAVING` clause, and you should have a `GROUP BY` clause on field1 and field2. The reason is that `COUNT()` is an aggregate function. Because `field1` and `field2` appear outside an aggregatee function, aggregation for those fields must be enforced with a `GROUP BY` clause. Most RDBMS-es won't allow you to write this unless there is an appropriate `GROUP BY` clause, but MySQL will, and will silently return rubbish for those fields.

BTW - I think you should probably not write `"false"` but simply `FALSE` - right now both legs of the choice have a different type (boolean vs string). The db will probably coerce types, but it is still bad practice. You should ensure that the expression for each brach of the `CASE` expression have the same data type.